# SWIFT: How to retrieve an array of strings from Firebase?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

I have an array with names written in Firebase **guestsOnTable : ["Joni", "Mike", "Will", "Nicole", "Tim"]**.
I need this array to retrieve and display in a UITableView. In every single row to display one name.
I'm new in Swift so this is first time I do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourArray.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
yourLabel.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]
}}
```